# How can I remove a custom event from my Fabric Answers dashboard?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have some events I no longer wish to see in my Fabric dashboard, as they are no longer active in the app.  How can I remove these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

Once the event doesn't receive any data within 30 days, it will be removed from your Fabric dashboard automatically. There isn't a way to manually remove events currently.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following your question and how it related to the original post. Can you please clarify it?

Comment: Per Stack Overflow guidelines, if you have a separate unrelated question, please ask a new question.